# DNS failure coinciding with user session removed

Tags: networking, dns, nodejs

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and running a nodejs program that is polling a REST api. It was working for about 3 hours polling the same web site every few seconds and then it failed saying it could not find the site. I'm getting an error from node: "failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND".

This is a node program that I had begun running via nohup & and had then logged out. It had been working which I could verify via my web site and because the process had been creating a log file of output while operating.

This seemed very odd because it had been going to the same address for hours. I checked the logs. In auth.log at the same that my output logging had stopped, I saw the following entry:

```
May 24 01:38:29 order-gateway systemd-logind[1028]: Removed session 237.
```

At this point (01:38) there was no user logged in. Session 237 had been initiated:

```
May 23 17:22:38 order-gateway systemd-logind[1028]: New session 237 of user ubuntu.
```

I believe that the session that I initiated the process in was 238 (though I'm not sure). It does not make any sense to me that 1) a session is removed hours after the user logs out and 2) that removing a session causes a hiccup in the DNS.

Add'l info: resolv.conf is set automatically and uses Google's DNS (8.8.8.8). Here is what I have:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search openstacklocal
```

I did not set it up. Please help. I'd love to learn what is going on and, of course, fix the problem.

Update:
I have been monitoring the situation and have confirmed that when the session that I initiated the process is removed (systemd-logind[1001]) that the process records an error and ends. This is after I have edited the logind.conf to uncomment KillUserProcesses=no so that user processes should not get killed.

Addl Update:
The causal direction is becoming not so clear. I am suspecting that the endpoint is potentially unstable and that kill process occurs just after the program fails. I'd like to understand why the DNS becomes unstable. Support suggested manually adding the endpoint to /etc/hosts which appears to have worked (another issue subsequently killed the program but it ran far longer than I would have expected which is why I'm thinking to invert the causality).